# Jcrop Touch support not working - Webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix, jcrop

I followed Mike Brind's guide [webimage helper with jcrop](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/161/webmatrix-testing-the-webimage-helper-with-jcrop) and it works great on a pc but on a phone with touch it does nothing. You can still see the crop outline but cannot do anything with it. I checked and it is supposed to support touch and going to deep liquid's website it does work on my phone. Anyone know of a reason it may not work on my site?

I am  even using all the demo files available from deep liquid and it still does not work with touch.